# One repository to two databases, MongoDB and Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, repository

I have a repository which I want to save inside two different MongoDB databases, programmatically.

If the user enters an URL with the parameter DB1, the repository will save inside the database DB1, if it is DB2, to the database DB2, etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically. You need to have the application connected to 2 DBs and call each one depending on the parameter that comes in from the request. You'll need two separate repositories as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do with repositories easily (use multiple repositories with a little modification, because we can't use one, for each parameter in the URL is a madness.

So to avoid a lot of duplicate code we have to use the Java Driver.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

//here we can change the database name
MongoOperations mongoOperations = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, database);

mongoOperations.save(YOUR_POJO);

mongoClient.close();
```

The POJO object has to use de `@Document`annotation, if not you will have codec problems. Here you can solve them: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/bson/codecs/